# Suggestions for Python debugging tools?

Tags: python, debugging, simulation

Yesterday I made a simulation using Python. I had a few difficulties with **variables and debugging**.

Is there any software for Python, which provides a decent debugger?

Related question: [What is the best way to debug my Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299704/what-is-the-best-way-to-debug-my-python-code)

Comment: Added a link to related question.

Comment: I recommend Thonny (http://thonny.cs.ut.ee)

Comment: I developed PySnooper, which can be a useful alternative to a full-blown debugger: https://github.com/cool-RR/PySnooper/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't forget about post-mortem debugging!  After an exception is thrown, the stack frame with all of the locals is contained within `sys.last_traceback`.  You can do `pdb.pm()` to go to the stack frame where the exception was thrown then p(retty)p(rint) the `locals()`.

Here is a function that uses this information to extract the local variables from the stack.

```
def findlocals(search, startframe=None, trace=False):

    from pprint import pprint
    import inspect, pdb

    startframe = startframe or sys.last_traceback
    frames = inspect.getinnerframes(startframe)

    frame = [tb for (tb, _, lineno, fname, _, _) in frames
             if search in (lineno, fname)][0]

    if trace:
        pprint(frame.f_locals)
        pdb.set_trace(frame)
    return frame.f_locals
```

Usage:

```
>>> def screwyFunc():
    a = 0
    return 2/a

>>> screwyFunc()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    screwyFunc()
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 3, in screwyFunc
    return 2/a
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
>>> findlocals('screwyFunc')
{'a': 0}
```

Comment: I like this answer much! It reminds me the new outstanding answer in one thread of mine about Python local modules where it took about 5 years that we got forward. It would be great if you can compare and contrast your answer to JackWu's answer.

Answer (score 33):

`Winpdb` ([archived link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090126223735/http://winpdb.org/) / [SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winpdb/files/winpdb/) / [Google Code Archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/winpdb/downloads)) is a **platform independent** graphical GPL Python debugger with support for remote debugging over a network, multiple threads, namespace modification, embedded debugging, encrypted communication and is up to 20 times faster than pdb.

Features:

- GPL license. Winpdb is Free Software.
- Compatible with CPython 2.3 through 2.6 and Python 3000
- Compatible with wxPython 2.6 through 2.8
- Platform independent, and tested on Ubuntu Gutsy and Windows XP.
- User Interfaces: rpdb2 is console based, while winpdb requires wxPython 2.6 or later.

Alternative: `Fork of the official winpdb` ([winpdb-reborn · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/winpdb-reborn/) / [GitHub](https://github.com/bluebird75/winpdb))

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [winpdb.org](http://winpdb.org/images/screenshot_winpdb_small.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 29):

[pudb](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) is a visual debugger for python.

[image: pudb screenshot]

Comment: pudb is all I've ever wanted in a debugging tool. regular pdb is just not user friendly. pudb gives the visual feedback I need. Thanks for suggesting it

Comment: `python -m pudb script.py` and you are debugging the code without modifying it

Answer (score 12):

As [the post](https://zapier.com/engineering/debugging-python-boss/) suggested, there are a few options:

- pdb: Python's built-in debugger
  [image: pdb]
  <sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/e52a752629759a90fda41a1081b79e15.png))</sub>
- pudb: GUI debugger
  [image: pudb]
  <sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/d208c2195f1b6a4f0dbf29ac1835867e.png))</sub>
- pydbgr: a rewrite of the pydb debugger
  [image: pydbgrb]
  <sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/895b7a2bf7fb58745ad3213034f31aba.png))</sub>
- ipdb: iPython's ipdb
  [image: ipdb]
  <sub>(source: [cachefly.net](https://zapier.cachefly.net/storage/photos/c2c727c6672601697892ce55d41b2476.png))</sub>

Comment: I find the visual debugger built into Spyder IDE very handy for scientific debugging esp involving matrices. Maybe you could add that to your answer?

Answer (score 11):

You can check out the python debugger pdb, which is included in the standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend [pydb](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/pydb/) and [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) for interactive debugging.

Both have screencasts available at [showmedo.com](http://showmedo.com)

- [Introduction to pydb](http://showmedo.com/videos/video?name=pythonBernsteinPydbIntro)
- [The showmedo series on IPython](http://showmedo.com/videos/series?name=CnluURUTV)

Comment: Is there a tutorial you'd recommend for getting started?

Comment: Yup, the showmedo screencasts.

Comment: pydb is now called trepan. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan or  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/trepan3k. (When Polish-speaking people tell you your name is unpronounceable, it's time to change the name)

Answer (score 6):

[Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/store/productdetail.aspx?prdGuid=64816ba8-b5fe-4e8d-8084-a6e66743ca78&) (not the free [Komodo Edit](http://www.openkomodo.com/)) comes with a debugger.  I haven't used it in over a year, but it was good back then (v 3, IIRC).

Comment: Komodo has definitely been nice for debugging.

Comment: How does the debugger differ in Komodo Edit from the one in Komodo IDE?
For me, the Komodo Edit solved three indentation problems fast taday.

Comment: Maybe they've added it in the newer version.  It definitely didn't have one 18 months ago!

Answer (score 3):

There is an Eclipse plug-in for Python which supports debugging, among other tools. See the The [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Python/article.html) to start with, and the [Website](http://pydev.org/) for download. Off course you will need to get [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I used PyCharm and WingIDE for debugging, both are great.

PyCharm uses quite some RAM (it's in Java), still, I ended up using it as I can debug doctests that I'm executing from it.

WindIDE is written in Python, I like it more than PyCharm except for the lack of running doctests.

You can also try Spyder, which I never succeeded to make work.

Comment: +1 for PyCharm, super easy to set breakpoints. Plus, I find it especially useful for Django projects. It's also free for open source projects!

Comment: For web projects Werkzeug seems awesome, its like a Python console right in your browser that can access your locals.  You can code right in Werkzeug then when you get your code right you can copy/paste it into your editor.

Answer (score 2):

See official [Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) for suggestions. Feel free to update and subscribe to receive notifications when something new comes out.