# Debuging .py code called from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I'm really new to python and used to work with matlab and I'm getting really frustrated about the debugging capabilities with python.

I'm currently trying to do a homework task given in CS231 course (http://cs231n.github.io/), and I'm working with pyCharm (and anaconda). In the homework I have a .ipynb (jupyter notebook file) that guides me through the assignment and in that file I have calls to .py files where I write my own code. 
I'm trying to figure out a way to debug the code I write. In matlab I could easily set a break point inside the code I wrote and debug it when an external function calls it, while in python, I can't set a breakpoint and debug a code that is called from a jupyter notebook (it just ignores the breakpoint).

Is there a way of doing so? And if not what is the best way to debug those kind of stuff?
And less importantly but why is it so difficult to easily debug code in python as opposed to matlab?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suggestions for Python debugging tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477193/suggestions-for-python-debugging-tools)

Comment: Debugging is great within Pycharm (as easy as in Matlab, maybe even easier). The problem is not Python in general but the use of ipython notebooks.
Maybe this can help find workarounds: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000104824-How-to-debug-Jupyter-notebooks-in-PyCharm-

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm Professional 2019 allows you to [run and debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-jupyter-notebook-cells.html) Jupyter Notebook cells.