# django development mode runserver --noreload hits 100 percent cpu usage

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

i have setup on pydev eclipse

everytime i run runserver --noreload  my cpu usage hits to 100 percent on core 2 duo laptop ..

pretty much this guy had the same problem

[Django development server CPU intensive - how to analyse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750676/django-development-server-cpu-intensive-how-to-analyse)

i tried on a quad core machine it gets to 30 percent cpu usage too. i guess the runserver is not very effective ? i am doing any big thing .. just started to learn django here.

any thoughts what might cause this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I started using Aptana (eclipse) on my mac for django development and had all kinds of problems with configuring it and slow running.  Switched to [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and my problems went away.  Not a solution for everyone but worked for me.