# Django / psycopg2 / postgresql probably broken models give useless stack trace

Tags: python, django, postgresql, stack-trace

I'm working on integrating OpenID with my own authentication Stack for Django. I'm using python-openid, django 1.2.5 with postgresql, following the examples from the djopenid folder under `examples/`

What's happening is this. I'm using a view that calls python-openid's various mechanisms, which rely on models I've fed in. Somewhere in there, something's breaking. My problem is not *why* it is broken, it is the fact that I can't tell *what* is broken. My models are written directly against their implementation comments, but I have probably made a mistake or two.

This is the stack trace:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=5476): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 
'/var/www/Django/Testbed/Testbed.wsgi'., referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
 Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 
252, in __call__, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     response = middleware_method(request, response), referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File 
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 
36, in process_response, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     request.session.save(), referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File 
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 
61, in save, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     sid = transaction.savepoint(using=using), referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 229, 
in savepoint, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     connection._savepoint(sid), referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 
56, in _savepoint, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     self.cursor().execute(self.ops.savepoint_create_sql(sid)), referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 15, 
in execute, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params), referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
   File 
"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py
", line 44, in execute, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
     return self.cursor.execute(query, args), referer: 
http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
 DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of 
transaction block, referer: http://localhost/testbed/openidlogin
```

So I understand django is using [postgresql transaction management](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#handling-exceptions-within-postgresql-transactions) and that somewhere in this process I'm doing *something* that causes an integrity issue with the database. But it doesn't tell me what that might be, or where the error is in my code. I've tried [turning this off](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#how-to-globally-deactivate-transaction-management) in `settings.py` to see if a more sensible stack trace results. It doesn't.

My question is very simple: How do I find out where the problem is? I can work backwards from an offending SQL statement (since that will tell me which models are failing) or even better a stack trace involving some of my code. Even "postgresql error code XYZ" gives me something to google. Are there some settings I can turn on that make django a little more talkative? I'm using

```
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
```

Obviously, but I'm not even getting a yellow error page. Just your plain old 500 Internal Server Error and that stack trace in the error log of apache. Is there somewhere else I can look? Some option I can enact or some whizzy tool that I can use to watch execution or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run it via manage.py on some port, place **ipdb.set_trace()** call in your view and trace it step by step - like in any other debugging process.

Also you can use [built-in python/django logging features](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/) and just print our stuff to the log file.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips) for more tips - maybe some of them will be usefull for you.

Comment: Aaaah. Now that's a good idea and will hopefully help me work out what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: did you finally found the problem? we have randomly this error using django-social-auth. thanks.