# Apportable porting from Cocos2d project error

Tags: android, porting, apportable

I'm now trying to port one of my Cocos2d 1.x project using Apportable, getting following error on compile stage:

```
     apk = env.BuildAPK(os.path.join(env['VARIANT_DIR'], env['APPLICATION_NAME'], config['APPLICATION_NAME'] + '.apk'), lib, assets + env['LIBRARY_ASSETS'])
  File "/Users/*user*/.apportable/SDK/lib/scons/engine/SCons/Environment.py", line 223, in __call__
    return self.method(*nargs, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/*user*/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/sdk.py", line 1123, in APKBuilder
    packaged = ResourcesFinalize(env, target=res_apk_path, source=source, assets=assets)
  File "/Users/*user*/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/sdk.py", line 922, in ResourcesFinalize
    all_assets = RemapAssetList(env, assets)
  File "/Users/*user*/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/sdk.py", line 847, in RemapAssetList
    (remap, target) = Remap(env, asset, target)
  File "/Users/*user*/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/sdk.py", line 723, in Remap
    (base, ext) = os.path.splitext(str(source))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0421' in position 58: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is it SDK problem or my source code is there solution to fix it?

Comment: just a guess, does your project's name or path have any non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 1):

As LearnCocos2D guessed, Apportable does not currently handle resource files with non-ASCII names.

If you want to leave the IOS project untouched, you can copy or link the resource file to an ASCII name and update configuration.json accordingly:

For example, on the remove_params section:

```
        "assets": [
              "Resources/Audio/@#$%\u2122!.wav",
               .....
```

And in the add_params section:

```
        "assets": [
               "apportable/Resources/sonOfA.wav",  // link to Resources/Audio/@#$%\u2122!.wav"
```

Also, we're now updating the Apportable platform to handle non-ASCII characters correctly, so if you're reading this more than a week or two in the future, the question will be moot.

Comment: Is there a way to detect which exactly file is wrong, there is about 500 files where probably by mistake inserted non ASCII symbols. If correctly understood it should be one of filename where is C letter represented.

Comment: Ok, seems found the way to find out non ASCII filename, on MAC navigated through Terminal to resources folder and executed command:
ls | perl -ne 'print if /[^[:ascii:]]/'

Comment: Nice find on how to track down the non-ASCII filenames. Another option is to take a look in the python debugger. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips