# Watch function calls and variable values?

Tags: python, trace

How can I watch which functions get called and all variable values in a Python script?

I have just discovered the uncertainties package for Python, and I want to actually figure out how it works so I can explain it to my boss.

Basically, I can't see how the uncertainties are actually calculated. This is probably because I don't know how Python works yet.

For starters, how can I see how `c` is calculated?

```
import uncertainties
from uncertainties import ufloat

a = ufloat(1,3)
b = ufloat(2,4)

c = a + b  # How does this work??

print c
```

Comment: I find google is usually more expedient than a debugger.  Have a look at the documentation.  Or, at the worst, just diving into the source, if you for example knew that objects can specify methods like `__add__` to implement behavior with arithmetic operators.

Comment: @roippi
The Python documentation I've come across is very different to the Javadocs I am used to and isn't all that intuitive to follow, and I also don't know how to build it (or if it exists) for the uncertainties package.


I know that objects can write their own `__add__` function , except that the way I think they get added by reflection, going by the comments, so trying to track everything through the source code is a little tricky.

Comment: Have you seen the [technical guide](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/tech_guide.html)?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida Yes. I've read the guide, and while it says what is going on, it doesn't say how it is doing it. I know how to calculate the errors, but I'd like to be able to reproduce each step that is done in this package to understand what is actually being done.

Comment: Side note: no need to have `import uncertainties` if you only use `ufloat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how things are calculated, `pdb` is indeed one solution.

However, with a debugger like `pdb`, it is hard to get a high-level overview of what is going on. This is why reading the code is also useful. For example, if you want to know what `a+b` does, you can check if `type(a).__add__` exists, because if it does, it handles the addition. This is the case with the uncertainties package.

That said, `__add__` is indeed implemented in uncertainties through a general mechanism instead of being specifically coded for, so I can tell you the idea behind its implementation, since this is what you seem to be ultimately looking for.

In your example, `a` and `b` are `Variable` objects:

```
>>> from uncertainties import ufloat                                            
>>> a = ufloat(1, 3)
>>> b = ufloat(2, 4)
>>> type(a)
<class 'uncertainties.Variable'>
```

Then `c = a + b` is actually a linear *function* of `a` and `b`, represented by its derivatives with respect to `a` and `b`:

```
>>> c = a + b
>>> type(c)
<class 'uncertainties.AffineScalarFunc'>
>>> c.derivatives
{1.0+/-3.0: 1.0, 2.0+/-4.0: 1.0}
```

If you know the derivatives of a function with respect to its variables, you can easily get an [approximation of its standard deviation from the standard deviations of its variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty).

Thus, the main ideas behind the implementation of the [uncertainties package](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) is that values are either:

- random variables like x = 3.14±0.0.1 and y = 0±0.01 (`Variable` objects), described by their standard deviation,
- or linear approximations of functions (`AffineScalarFunc` objects: "affine" because they are linear, "scalar" because their values are real, and "func" because they are functions).

To take a more complicated example, z = 2*x+sin(y) is approximated in (x, y) = (3.14, 0) as 2*x + y. In the implementation, since the approximation is linear, only the derivatives with respect to the variables are stored:

```
>>> x = ufloat(3.14, 0.01)
>>> y = ufloat(0, 0.01)
>>> from uncertainties.umath import sin
>>> z = 2*x + sin(y)
>>> type(z)
<class 'uncertainties.AffineScalarFunc'>
>>> z.derivatives
{3.14+/-0.01: 2.0, 0.0+/-0.01: 1.0}
```

The main work done by the uncertainties package is thus to calculate the derivatives of any function involving variables. This is done by the efficient method of [automatic differentiation](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/tech_guide.html#differentiation-method). Concretely, when you do something like `a+b`, Python automatically calls the `Variable.__add__()` method, which creates a new linear function by calculating the derivatives of `a+b` with respect to its variables (the derivatives are both one, because the derivative of `a` with respect to `a` is one, and the same for `b`). More generally, one adds *functions*, not pure variables: the derivatives of `f(a,b) + g(a,b)` with respect to `a` and `b` is calculated with the chain rule. This is how automatic differentiation works, and this is what is implemented in the uncertainties package. The key function here is `uncertainties.wrap()`. It is the largest and most complicated function of the whole package, but the code is largely commented, and [details on the method](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/tech_guide.html#differentiation-method) are available.

Derivatives then give you the standard deviation of the final function as a function of the standard deviations of the variables (the code of `AffineScalarFunc.std_dev()` is very simple: the more difficult task is to automatically calculate derivatives).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the specific case of the `uncertainties` module, Python provides the [`sys.settrace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function, which can be used to implement things like the [Smiliey application tracer](https://github.com/dhellmann/smiley)

For example, from the [docs](https://smiley.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using):

> In one terminal window, run the monitor command:
>
> ```
> $ smiley monitor
> ```
>
> In a second terminal window, use smiley to run an application. This
>   example uses test.py from the test_app directory in the smiley source
>   tree.
>
> ```
> $ smiley run ./test.py
> args: ['./test.py']
> input = 10
> Leaving c() [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> Leaving b()
> Leaving a()
> ```
>
> The monitor session will show the execution path and local variables
>   for the app.
>
> ```
> Starting new run: ./test.py
> test.py:   1: import test_funcs
> test.py:   1: import test_funcs
> test_funcs.py:   1: import sys
> test_funcs.py:   1: import sys
> test_funcs.py:   3: def gen(m):
> test_funcs.py:   8: def c(input):
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the Python debugger: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

As you may know, a debugger is designed to let you watch the parts of the program move during execution.

You might also want to take a look at the source code of the Uncertainties package at https://github.com/lebigot/uncertainties/

Comment: I've got the source; it's a bit of a slog to read through.

I'm also investigating pdb now...

Comment: FYI, pdb was basically a LMGTFY on the need for a debugger. I don't know that it's the best debugger out there; I'm not a Python programmer myself. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips (which I came across from Google) might also be of interest.