# Start debugger automatically, with no breakpoints?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

My application has `debug = True` configuration option which turns on many facilities useful for debugging. I figured that it would be a nice idea to enable the debugger when debug mode is turned on, but not the way `python -m pdb someapp` works. Instead, I'd like it to behave as if the user entered "cont" right at the startup, so that the debugger appears only when an exception was caught. How do I do that on the source code level?

Comment: [Python debugging tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips) SO question could be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import sys

def run_pdb_hook(*args, **kwargs):
    import pdb, traceback
    traceback.print_exception(*args, **kwargs)
    pdb.pm()

if debug:
    sys.excepthook = run_pdb_hook
```