# How to quickly debug misbehaving script in Python without pdb?

Tags: python, debugging

I have a high level logic error deep within my Python script, and `pdb` doesn't help to debug it. Is there any other way to see what is being executed after I run my script?

NOTE: `pdb` is too slow and inconvenient for me. I wish I could grep over all cases when my function is executed, instead of inspecting manually each and every call, set/unset breakpoints. The state is lost when I exit `pdb` and its user interface is more confusing than helpful - requires docs at hand.

Comment: Then don't accept that answer on and/or edit [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869451/how-to-quickly-debug-misbehaving-script-in-python). Please close this duplicate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the previous question is downvoted and should be deleted, no?

Comment: It is being down voted *in current form*, even a closed question can be reopened of edited and improved.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok, rewrote previous question. This can be removed now.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this using excellent [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module that comes with Python.

An example how to troubleshoot module installation problem:

```
python -m trace -t setup.py install > execution.log
```

This will dump all source line of `setup.py install` execution to `execution.log`. I found this to be more useful than `pdb` approach.