# PDB doesn't stop on breakpoint in multithreaded code

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I'm using multi-threaded code and PDB doesn't stop on manually set breakpoints:

```
(pdb) b filename:lineno
(pdb) c  # Runs without stopping
```

What could be the reason why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to attach a debugger to a multi-threaded Python process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701/is-there-a-way-to-attach-a-debugger-to-a-multi-threaded-python-process)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of September 2020, Python's pdb debugger does not support multi-threading.

Attempting to break on a different thread from where pdb started, will skip the breakpoints. This is due to the current implementation using [`sys.settrace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) which is thread-specific.

There's a [ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue41571) for implementing this functionality among other multi-threading additions.

Currently, the only option is to `pdb.set_trace()` on the same thread being debugged.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `pdb` use e.g. `web-pdb`.

https://pypi.org/project/web-pdb/

Comment: "Web-PDB maintains one debugger instance that traces only one thread. You should not call set_trace() from different threads to avoid race conditions. Each thread needs to be debugged separately one at a time."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could swear I used it a couple of years ago to debug a multithreaded cli app, but apparantly it was a different one. Sorry for the wrong information!