# Adding attributes to nodes,edges and graphs

Tags: python, networkx

I am a new user of python and `networkx` and I want to ask you that how to add attributes to graphs,nodes and edges in `networkx`?When I try to add it there is an error Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    G[1][3]['color']='blue'
KeyError: 3
```

I have searched for attribute package for `networkx` but not found.

Comment: Please share the code snippet that you have a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems your node `G[1]` doesn't have `four` children (3 wuold be the fourth and 0 the first).

According to the python documetation:

> **exception KeyError**
>       Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.

In other words `G[1][3]` does not exists.

If you are starting to Python, now is a good time to start to learn how to debug your code. That way you will get more tools for findout what's going on with your code.

You can start at: [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

or check this question:  [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)