# Python list indices json error

Tags: python, json, for-loop, while-loop, indexing

I really have no idea what's going on here -- let me outline the code.

I'm pulling data from the SFG WorldCup API.

Sample output from the API from earlier today:

```
[
    {
        "match_number": 26,
        "location": "Arena da Baixada",
        "datetime": "2014-06-20T19:00:00.000-03:00",
        "status": "in progress",
        "home_team": {
            "country": "Honduras",
            "code": "HON",
            "goals": 1
        },
        "away_team": {
            "country": "Ecuador",
            "code": "ECU",
            "goals": 2
        },
        "winner": null,
        "home_team_events": [
            {
                "id": 290,
                "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
                "player": "Bernardez",
                "time": "7"
            },
            {
                "id": 291,
                "type_of_event": "goal",
                "player": "Costly",
                "time": "31"
            },
            {
                "id": 294,
                "type_of_event": "substitution-in halftime",
                "player": "J.C. Garcia",
                "time": "46"
            },
            {
                "id": 297,
                "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
                "player": "M. Martinez",
                "time": "71"
            },
            {
                "id": 301,
                "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
                "player": "M. Chavez",
                "time": "83"
            },
            {
                "id": 293,
                "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
                "player": "Bengtson",
                "time": "453"
            }
        ],
        "away_team_events": [
            {
                "id": 292,
                "type_of_event": "goal",
                "player": "E. Valencia",
                "time": "34"
            },
            {
                "id": 295,
                "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
                "player": "A. Valencia",
                "time": "57"
            },
            {
                "id": 296,
                "type_of_event": "goal",
                "player": "E. Valencia",
                "time": "65"
            },
            {
                "id": 298,
                "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
                "player": "E. Valencia",
                "time": "73"
            },
            {
                "id": 299,
                "type_of_event": "yellow-card",
                "player": "Montero",
                "time": "80"
            },
            {
                "id": 300,
                "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
                "player": "Mendez",
                "time": "82"
            },
            {
                "id": 302,
                "type_of_event": "substitution-in",
                "player": "Gruezo",
                "time": "83"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

With this data, my problem is that getting data in the for loop works, but in a while loop below it doesn't.

`resp` is the response from the api...

```
     for jogo in resp.json():
         score = jogo['home_team']['goals']
     jogo = resp.json()
     while True:
         newscore = int(jogo['home_team']['goals'])
```

The actual code is a little different (the `jogo['home_team']['goals']` in the while loop is in an `if` statement, but this is the basic skeleton of it.

The error I get is on the one in the `while`, and it says `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I'm not sure if it's relevant that I'm comparing it to an integer (I have it wrapped in an `int()`).

What's causing this, and why isn't it being called on the first one.

Thanks!

evamvid

PS let me know if this doesn't make any sense =)

Comment: Print the `jogo` in your loop. See what it is. If `resp.json()` is what you pasted, i don't see a problem..

Comment: For further help, please post the entire related code, and the complete traceback, thanks!

Comment: Has `resp.json()` already been parsed? If not you'll need to parse it (eg with `json.loads(resp.json())`) before you can iterate over the elements (otherwise you're just iterating over characters in a string).

Comment: I added the variable declaration to the code.

Answer (score 0):

With the new code posted it makes more sense:

```
 # here, jogo takes the value of each dict{} within the outer list[]
 for jogo in resp.json():
     score = jogo['home_team']['goals']

 # while here it is the outer list itself 
 jogo = resp.json()
 while True:
     newscore = int(jogo['home_team']['goals'])
```

If you know there is only going to be a single result in the list, you can just use

```
 jogo = resp.json()[0]
```

The error is telling you that `jogo` expects an integer index (implying it is a list type or similar), but you're passing it a string index (showing you expected it to be a dict). This was the statement causing the error:

```
...jogo['home_team']...
```

The outer `int` call had no effect.

Comment: @evamvid No problem, take a look at this question for method on debugging Python code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips). You could probably have tracked this down yourself in a couple of minutes :)

Comment: The API I'm using is very time-specific -- it depends on whether or not a game is being played. I'll accept the answer tomorrow after I can confirm that it works. Thanks for the debugging info!!