# Stacktrace for UserWarning

Tags: python, warnings

I see a warning like this in my logs:

```
py.warnings.__init__: WARNING .../bs4/__init__.py:219: UserWarning: "foo" 
  looks like a filename, not markup. You should probably open this file 
  and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup
```

This message does not help very much.

I would like to see the stacktrace where this happens.

Please don't look into the content of this warning. This question is not about  Beautiful Soup :-)

An easy solution would be to modify the third party code (`bs4/__init__.py` at line 219) and add something like this:

```
import traceback
logger.warn('Exc at ...\n%s' % ''.join(traceback.format_stack()))
```

But I would like to avoid this. Reasons:

- This is a warning from a production system. I don't want to change the source.
- The next time a warning like this occurs, I would like to see the stacktrace immediately

Is there a flag or setting for python which I can change, to see not only one line, but the while stacktrace? I need the upper frames to debug this.

In this environment Python 2.7 gets used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do the following:

1. Create if USER_SITE does not exists: issue `python -c "import site; site._script()"`, see USER_SITE variable contents
2. Place a file `usercustomize.py` in that directory with the following code:

   ```
   import traceback
   import warnings


   _old_warn = warnings.warn
   def warn(*args, **kwargs):
       tb = traceback.extract_stack()
       _old_warn(*args, **kwargs)
       print("".join(traceback.format_list(tb)[:-1]))
   warnings.warn = warn
   ```

   Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29567225/5466126) answer for the code.

Run the code as usual. My test code:

```
import warnings

def f():
    warnings.warn("foz")

f()
```

Before the procedure:

```
$ python test_warn.py
test_warn.py:4: UserWarning: foz
  warnings.warn("foz")
```

After:

```
$ python test_warn.py
<USER_SITE_REDACTED>/usercustomize.py:6: UserWarning: foz
  _old_warn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "test_warn.py", line 6, in <module>
    f()
  File "test_warn.py", line 4, in f
    warnings.warn("foz")
```

Comment: OK, I see. AFAIK this is called monkey patching. Yes, I think usercustomize.py is a good place to do monkey patching like this. Thank you.

Comment: @guettli, it is monkeypatching. Although this might be a legitimate case for using it, given that the source is not to be changed, and the intrusion does not alter any logic - just effectively adds more logging.

Answer (score 2):

If I want to find the root of a warning I generally just promote `Warnings` to `Exceptions`.

In your case you could simply use [`warnings.simplefilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) or [`warnings.filterwarnings`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings).

For example:

```
import warnings

def func():
    warnings.warn('abc', UserWarning)
    
def func2():
    func()
    
# Here I promote all UserWarnings to exceptions, but you could also use "warnings.filterwarnings"
# to only promote warnings from a specified module or matching a specified message.
# You may need to check which is most useful/appropriate for you.
warnings.simplefilter("error", UserWarning)   # you might need to reset this later :)
func2()
```

which gives a complete traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserWarning                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-be791e1071e7> in <module>()
      8 
      9 warnings.simplefilter("error", UserWarning)
---> 10 func2()

<ipython-input-11-be791e1071e7> in func2()
      5 
      6 def func2():
----> 7     func()
      8 
      9 warnings.simplefilter("error", UserWarning)

<ipython-input-11-be791e1071e7> in func()
      2 
      3 def func():
----> 4     warnings.warn('abc', UserWarning)
      5 
      6 def func2():

UserWarning: abc
```

And if you want to debug this you could easily hook Pythons [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)s on the last encountered exception:

```
import pdb

pdb.pm()
```

resulting in:

```
> <ipython-input-11-be791e1071e7>(4)func()
-> warnings.warn('abc', UserWarning)
(Pdb) _________________
```

This starts a post-mortem analysis of the last encountered exception. Which should enable you to dig through the frames and inspect the variables, etc.

---

You also asked about a flag, and indeed there is a flag that enables "warning handling", the [`-W` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-w). It's very much like the `warnings.filterwarnings` function. For convenience I just copied the documentation of the `-W` flag here:

> Warning control. Python’s warning machinery by default prints warning messages to sys.stderr. A typical warning message has the following form:
>
> ```
> file:line: category: message
> ```
>
> By default, each warning is printed once for each source line where it occurs. This option controls how often warnings are printed.
>
> Multiple -W options may be given; when a warning matches more than one option, the action for the last matching option is performed. Invalid -W options are ignored (though, a warning message is printed about invalid options when the first warning is issued).
>
> Starting from Python 2.7, DeprecationWarning and its descendants are ignored by default. The -Wd option can be used to re-enable them.
>
> Warnings can also be controlled from within a Python program using the warnings module.
>
> The simplest form of argument is one of the following action strings (or a unique abbreviation) by themselves:
>
> - ignore
>
>   Ignore all warnings.
> - default
>
>   Explicitly request the default behavior (printing each warning once per source line).
> - all
>
>   Print a warning each time it occurs (this may generate many messages if a warning is triggered repeatedly for the same source line, such as inside a loop).
> - module
>
>   Print each warning only the first time it occurs in each module.
> - once
>
>   Print each warning only the first time it occurs in the program.
> - error:
>
>   Raise an exception instead of printing a warning message.
>
> The full form of argument is:
>
> ```
> action:message:category:module:line
> ```
>
> Here, action is as explained above but only applies to messages that match the remaining fields. Empty fields match all values; trailing empty fields may be omitted. The message field matches the start of the warning message printed; this match is case-insensitive. The category field matches the warning category. This must be a class name; the match tests whether the actual warning category of the message is a subclass of the specified warning category. The full class name must be given. The module field matches the (fully-qualified) module name; this match is case-sensitive. The line field matches the line number, where zero matches all line numbers and is thus equivalent to an omitted line number.

Comment: I guess this is not addressed in your anwer: The next time a warning like this occurs, I would like to see the stacktrace immediately

Comment: You will See the traceback immediatly if you promote them to exceptions. Or did i misunderstood your question?

Comment: I misunderstood you solution yesterday. I think now I understood it. You "Raise an exception instead of printing a warning message."  I would like to avoid this, since the warning happens on a production environment, and up to now it is not repeatable in a development environment. I would like to avoid switching from a warning to exception in this case.