# Python: an up-to-date GUI debugger for Python2.7 and Python3.x, without IDE

Tags: python, debugging

I am looking for a Python debugger with the following features:

1. **Up-to-date** - I searched in the web and found debuggers that were last updated in 2009-2010. This is too old and implies that is not supported anymore...
2. **Has GUI**
3. **Is standalone** - I don't want to load a whole IDE for debugging some released application
4. **Supports Python2.7 and Python 3.x**

Can you recommend me on such a debugger?

**EDIT:**

From research and from the answers, it seems that there is no debugger that satisfies all the requirements:

- **winpdb** was last updated in 2009/2010
- **pudb** GUI is console based (Like **vi editor**) - not very convenient and modern
- Other standalone debuggers have no GUI at all
- Other debuggers are not standalone, but are a part of IDEs - not convenient for debugging released applications

If there's an update - I'll write it here...

Comment: Sorry this is off-topic, asking for recommendations is not on-topic here. Better for here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You'll find here everything you need :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb

or

> http://winpdb.org/about/

I guess. Haven't used either though.

Comment: `winpdb` was last updated in 2009 or 2010... `pudb` has UI like VI editor... I want something with better UI and under maintenance

Comment: I'm afraid you are out of options than. I've never seen a stand alone guish debugger for python at all tbh.

Comment: The only option I can see is the pycharm's community edition. It is and IDE, yes, but pretty light weight compared to Pro

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will approach this http://pybee.org/bugjar/. This debugger has not all features, but it works.

Comment: It would be constructive to list which features the OP requires that this debugger has.