# How to tell what a python script is doing while running?

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a script to scrape some web data in Python27. But with certain websites, the script gets stuck and seems to run forever.

Is there a way to follow what it is working on while the script is running?

I would like to understand where it is getting stuck, or if in fact it is doing something.

I'm new python. But I'm a little more familiar with Ruby on Rails. So I'm imagining something like watching the console in Rails while navigating the app after launching with 'rails s'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips any use?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up and use a transparent proxy (burpsuite) and check the logs where the script gets stuck. 
Incase you are using requests module, use the following code.

```
http_proxy  = "localhost:8080"
https_proxy = "localhost:8080"
proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy
            }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxyDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the python script from the console, you could do something like this

**example.py**

```
while condition: 
    print "I'm inside the while loop"
```

After that, you are able to run

```
python example.py
```

And you must see `"I'm inside the while loop"` in the console till the condition become `false`. If you want print the value of a varible you have to follow the following steps:

```
variable      = 45
text_variable = "hello"

while condition: 
    print "{0} -- {1}".format(variable,text_variable)
```

Then you will see in the console

```
45 -- hello
45 -- hello 
# And so on, until the condition returns false
```