# Does Python have anything like bash -x

Tags: python, bash, echo, execution

When running a bash script you can pass -x, and it will print out each line of the script as it executes. Is there anything similar in Python?

Comment: This might help: [Python debugging tips](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1623039/3776858)

Comment: You can also use [`sys.settrace`](http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/20/tracing_python_code.html).