# Need help describing and understanding some python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand each line of code in this program. Thanks

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
s = sentence.split() 
another = [0] 

 print(sentence)
for count, x in enumerate(s): 
    if s.count(x) < 2:
        another.append(max(another) + 1)
    else:
        another.append(s.index(x) +1)
another.pop(0) 

print(another)
```

Comment: Would you mind to take a Python manual and read a little bit?

Comment: This is not a tutoring service.

Comment: use `print()` after every line and print variables and you see what this functions do.

Comment: we can help you with coding problems, but we can not *understand things for you*.

Comment: hi please do you code in python terminal then  you get more idea, always try to understand code by other

Answer (score 0):

[Python debugger 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929251/can-you-step-through-python-code-to-help-debug-issues)

[Python debugger 02](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)

[python debugger 03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)

[Python debugger 04](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2012/04/06/stop-using-print-for-debugging-a-5-minute-quickstart-guide-to-pythons-logging-module/)

Use this resources to aid your research on how to debug and understand code.