# python: How to trace function execution order in large project

Tags: python, visualization, profile, trace, execution

I want to trace function/class executive order in scrapy framework. There are multiple *.py files across the default project, and I want to know which py file and class has been executed in order. It sound silly to put logger line in every class and function.  How to visualize this order?

cprofile is mainly used for measuring total time. I could also visualize the execution order inside one module, which is common question, but visualizing multiple modules are difficult.

In terms of trace package, I did not find appropriate examples to work with large project like scrapy or django. Trace usage tutorial is about a single python file.

I want to trace multiple *.py files in multiple modules in a large project, eg scrapy, instead of just one module.

I am aware of debug tools like pdb, but I find it cumbersome to put break point across the whole project. More importantly, it is not easy to summarize the execution order.

**Finally** I solved by using Hunter, which is better than build-in trace module. Trace module did not offer include_dir attribute.

For those who are curiosity about how to trace all lines of scrapy.

```
$PYTHONHUNTER='Q(module_startswith=["scrapy", "your_project"])' scrapy list
```

In terms of django, tracing execution codes of rest_framework and save to test.log, for example:

```
$PYTHONHUNTER='Q(module_startswith=["rest_framework", "your_project"]), action=CallPrinter(stream=open("test.log", "w"))' python manage.py runserver --noreload --nothreading
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Python Call Graph` ? , Python Call Graph is a Python module that creates call graph visualizations for Python applications.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## trace

> The [trace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module allows you to trace program execution, generate
>   annotated statement coverage listings, print caller/callee
>   relationships and list functions executed during a program run. It can
>   be used in another program or from the command line.

```
python -m trace --count -C . somefile.py ...
```

The above will execute `somefile.py` and generate annotated listings of all Python modules imported during the execution into the current directory.

## PDB

> The module [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) defines an interactive source code debugger for Python
>   programs. It supports setting (conditional) breakpoints and single
>   stepping at the source line level, inspection of stack frames, source
>   code listing, and evaluation of arbitrary Python code in the context
>   of any stack frame. It also supports post-mortem debugging and can be
>   called under program control.

Most Common Used Command:

**w(here)**

- Print a stack trace, with the most recent frame at the bottom. An
  arrow indicates the current frame, which determines the context of
  most commands.

**d(own)**

- Move the current frame one level down in the stack trace (to a newer
  frame).

**u(p)**

- Move the current frame one level up in the stack trace (to an older
  frame).

You can also check this question [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)

## Coverage

> [Coverage.py](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/) measures code coverage, typically during test execution.
>   It uses the code analysis tools and tracing hooks provided in the
>   Python standard library to determine which lines are executable, and
>   which have been executed.

## Hunter

> [Hunter](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-hunter) is a flexible code tracing toolkit, not for measuring coverage,
>   but for debugging, logging, inspection and other nefarious purposes.

The default action is to just print the code being executed. Example:

```
import hunter
hunter.trace(module='posixpath')

import os
os.path.join('a', 'b')
```

Result in terminal:
[image: Hunter Result in terminal]

Comment: I want to trace multiple *.py files in multiple modules in a large project, for example scrapy framework, instead of just one module.

Comment: What do you want to find out from your project code ?

Comment: Hunter is amazing. After a few days trying different tools, I find hunter is good enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Well the best tool to trace function execution order is definitely [viztracer](https://github.com/gaogaotiantian/viztracer). I would have to say that visualization is a huge factor when it comes to understanding a larger project.

[image]

An interactive image like this makes it much easier to understand what's going on in your program, compared to cold terminal ascii.

Also, it's a non-intrusive tool, which means you don't need to write a single line of code. Just install it and run your program with it.

```
pip install viztracer
viztracer your_script.py
```

Another important factor here is that viztracer supports multi-thread and multi-process, and can visualize them in separate signals, on the same timeline, which you'll never achieve with terminal display.

Comment: I tried it, it's a very nice tool. Thanks a lot.