# Python Order of Execution Libraries / Tools

Tags: python, code-coverage, order-of-execution

I'm trying to bugfix a pretty large codebase (~100 000 lines) of purely python code and it would be very helpful to have a way to see what code is being run and in which order.  Does anyone know of a tool to do so?  I've used coverage to see what's being run but it gives me no indication of the order (which is very important to have more visibility into data preparation). I also cannot simply using logging as there are far too many things to log.  Please let me know; it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50558849) appears similar to your question.

Looks like the answer they have listed is something like this:

> The `trace` module allows you to trace program execution, generate annotated statement coverage listings, print caller/callee relationships and list functions executed during a program run. It can be used in another program or from the command line.
>
> ```
> python -m trace --count -C . somefile.py ...
> ```