# How to print post request data in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, debugging

In PHP when I send post request data from template `form` to controller I can use `print_r($data)` to `print` `form` send data for debugging purpose but in Django how can I print post request `form` data in **view.py**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you get your form data like PHP you may use

`from django.http import HttpResponse`

```
return HttpResponse(request.POST.items())
```

And for more debuging follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)