# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This error occurs in my code: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'`. What can I do to resolve it?

```
def report(grid_scores, n_top=3):
    top_scores = sorted(grid_scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n_top]
    for i, score in enumerate(top_scores):
        print("Rank: {0}".format(i + 1))
        print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.3f})".format(
              score.mean_validation_score,
              np.std(score.cv_validation_scores)))
        print("Parameters: {0}".format(score.parameters))
        print("")
report(clf.cv_results_)
```

Comment: Can you include what `grid_scores` is with some dummy data ? Im guessing its `clf.grid_scores_` from sklearn library ? If so please show us the cross validation code.

Comment: You need to provide more details

Comment: details about what?

Comment: Read my first comment

Comment: i can't include grid_scores

Comment: I cant help you

Comment: can you try with: `sorted(grid_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n_top]` to be `grid_scores` looks like a dict and you are trying to sort it by values.

Comment: you mean to replace sorted(grid_scores.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n_top] by grid_scores??

Comment: Check my answer a bit below. You copypasted from the sklearn documentation the example on how to do a grid search for an RF classifier. The problem is, that tutorial is really old (sklearn 0.15) and those methods were deprecated long ago. Check https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html for the new methods.

Answer (score 3):

The error is quite clear: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean_validation_score'`

There is only one place you use `mean_validation_score` and the object you use it on is a `string` - not what *you* think it is. `string` does not support the method you use on it - hence the error:

> ```
>     for i, score in enumerate(top_scores):                              # score from here
>         print("Rank: {0}".format(i + 1))
>         print("Mean validation score: {0:.3f} (std: {1:.3f})".format(
>               score.mean_validation_score,                              # usage here
>               np.std(score.cv_validation_scores)))
> ```

Obviosly the `top_scores` is a iterable of type string - hence when you enumerate it

> ```
> for i, score in enumerate(top_scores):
> ```

it produces indexes `i` and strings `score`.

You can resolve it by debugging your code:

> ```
> top_scores = sorted(grid_scores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:n_top]
> ```

and see why there are strings in it - fix that so it contains the objects that have `.mean_validation_score` and the error vanishes.

---

Helpful:

- [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools
- [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Ghost - not sure how I would be able to make this an better answer with your comment  and the incomplete code given by the OP 3y prior. Care to elaborate? Whatever you think the OP did - the code and error message pasted point to `score` being a string and not having the method he wants.

Comment: Patrick, you are literally not stating anything in your answer, just re-writing the same sentence as he got in the error message. The OP clearly asked hoping that whoever answered knows what the problem is about. Look my answer below, i addressed the issue there. He is using the grid_search method for sklearn RF directly from the documentation, which is a really old and deprecated version (0.15 vs current 1.1.1).

You can't make your answer better, because you have no idea what the OP issue is about, you shouldn't have even tried to answer in the first place.

Comment: @ghost I see, Well - people searching for the error on SO will now find both answers. Maybe yours will help 3 years after asking :)

Comment: Yeah, i know.. he probably figured it out by now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the `grid_search` method from the sklearn 0.15-0.17 version to fit RF args, which was long ago deprecated. The new method for the scores is not even `grid_scores_`, but `cv_results_`.

Check this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

And replace the statistic `mean_validation_score` with the one better for your args sweep.

Or if you want just a complete summary, forget of calling `report()` just do a `pd.DataFrame(random_search.cv_results_)`, sort by `rank_test_score` and that's it.