# For Loop Seems to be Adding on More to a Variable than it should

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I want to create a loop that will increase the cost of an item any given amount of times while also logging the total of cost of the instance. The issue is that whenever I execute the program the output seems to be more than it should be, and if I change the value of the variable `cost` to 10, then it seems to go over slightly more than it should. Here's the code:

```
amount = 3
cost = 0
increase = 10

for i in range(amount):
  cost += increase
  increase += increase


total = cost
print(total)
```

When `cost = 0` total becomes 70, when I think it should be 60, and then when `cost = 10` total becomes 80 when I think it should be 90.

Any help would be appreciated- sorry for asking such a stupid question. It's probably a super simple fix.

Comment: Why do you think it should be 60? `0 + 10 + 20 + 40` is 70.

Comment: *Why* do you think those are the correct values?  What have you done to trace the execution of your program?

Comment: `increase` **doubles** each time, it doesn't increase with `10` each time.

Comment: `print(i, cost, increase)` as the 1st and last line in the loop, to visualize how variable values evolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You double `increase` every time through the loop.  I'm not sure how you expect to get 60 and 90 for results.  I inserted a simple `print` at the bottom of the loop:

```
for i in range(amount):
  cost += increase
  increase += increase
  print("TRACE", cost, increase)
```

Output:

```
TRACE 10 20
TRACE 30 40
TRACE 70 80
70
```

Does this let you solve your problem?  Perhaps what you need is to increase `cost` be an linearly escalating amount:

```
for i in range(amount):
  cost += increase
  increase += 10
```

Output:

```
TRACE 10 20
TRACE 30 30
TRACE 60 40
60
```

Answer (score 3):

Pen + Paper helps to understand algorithms. In a pinch: comments inside the editor will do:

```
amount = 3
cost = 0
increase = 10

for i in range(amount)  #  0  #  1 #  2     # rounds
  cost += increase      # 10  # 30 # 70     # cost after increase
  increase += increase  # 20  # 40 # 80     # increased doubles

  # print(i, cost , increase)   # or debugging via outputting


total = cost                                # senseless
print(total) # 70
```

You might want to investigate [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips)

Comment: I see. Knew I was doing something wrong. I was referring to the beginning instance of increase rather than looking at the new one.