# How to execute line by line python commands from Linux Terminal?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, terminal, executable

I searched over the website, but I couldn't exactly find the answer to my question.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

e.g. in my python script (FileName.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
a = 1
b = 2
```

Now, I want to execute it line by line (MATLAB-like) from Terminal. For example when I press `a + b`, it should return the value `3`.

Comment: you can use IPython => https://ipython.org/

Comment: you can copy paste or import the code is that what yoiu mean?, if so type python in the terminal then from FileName import * should load a and b in your session

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929251/608639) Also see [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1623039/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to run python with `-i` flag. From `python --help`:

> -i     : inspect interactively after running script;

After the script is finished running, it will take you directly to the interpreter preserving declared global variables.

`python -i FileName.py`

```
>>> a + b
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, you type `python` & press enter key then it shows you `>>>>` character in the new line.
After that, type

```
//variable declaration,
a = 2
b = 3

//add the numbers,
a + b
```

**Output :**

It show you the output like ,

```
>>>>> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If Python is in your environment variables, type "Python" in your terminal screen. If not, type "Python" within Python's folder and you will see ">>>". It works the same way as Idle.
Alternatively you can use Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: I see >>>, but I want to use my code from python script. I have a=1, b=2 in my python script, now by typing in a+b in Terminal I want to execute a+b.

Comment: Basically, kinda debugging

Comment: Type "a=1" then Enter. Type "b=2" then Enter. Type "a + b" then Enter. Alternatively you can paste the lines from you script or try Jupyter Notebooks.