# How do I get scrapy pipeline to fill my mongodb with my items?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, scrapy, pymongo

How do I get scrapy pipeline to fill my mongodb with my items? Here is what my code looks like at the moment which is a reflection of the information i got off of scrapy documentation.
I also want to mention that I have tried returning items instead of yielding, as well tried using item loaders. All methods seem to have the same outcome.
on that note I want to mention that if I run the command
`mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycoll --drop --jsonArray --file ~/path/to/scrapyoutput.json`
my database gets populated(as long as I yield and don't return items)... I would really love to get this pipeline working though...

okay so here is my code:

here is my spider

```
    import scrapy

    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
    from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
    from capstone.items import CapstoneItem

    class CongressSpider(CrawlSpider):
        name = "congress"
        allowed_domains = ["www.congress.gov"]
        start_urls = [
            'https://www.congress.gov/members',
        ]
    #creating a rule for my crawler. I only want it to continue to the next page, don't follow any other links.
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(),restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='next']",)), callback="parse_page", follow=True),)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        for search in response.selector.xpath(".//li[@class='compact']"):
            yield {
                'member' : ' '.join(search.xpath("normalize-space(span/a/text())").extract()).strip(),
                'state' : ' '.join(search.xpath("normalize-space(div[@class='quick-search-member']//span[@class='result-item']/span/text())").extract()).strip(),
                'District' : ' '.join(search.xpath("normalize-space(div[@class='quick-search-member']//span[@class='result-item'][2]/span/text())").extract()).strip(),
                'party' : ' '.join(search.xpath("normalize-space(div[@class='quick-search-member']//span[@class='result-item'][3]/span/text())").extract()).strip(),
                'Served' : ' '.join(search.xpath("normalize-space(div[@class='quick-search-member']//span[@class='result-item'][4]/span//li/text())").extract()).strip(),
            }
```

settings:

```
    BOT_NAME = 'capstone'

    SPIDER_MODULES = ['capstone.spiders']
    NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'capstone.spiders'

    ITEM_PIPLINES = {'capstone.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,}
    MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    MONGO_DATABASE = 'congress'
    ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10
```

here is my pipeline.py
        import pymongo

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from scrapy.conf import settings
    from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
    from scrapy import log

    class MongoDBPipeline(object):
        collection_name= 'members'
        def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
            self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
            self.mongo_db = mongo_db
        @classmethod
        def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
            return cls(
                mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI')
                mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
            )
        def open_spider(self,spider):
            self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
            self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]
        def close_spider(self, spider):
            self.client.close()
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
            return item
```

here is items.py
        import scrapy

```
    class CapstoneItem(scrapy.Item):
        member = scrapy.Field()
        state = scrapy.Field()
        District = scrapy.Field()
        party = scrapy.Field()
        served = scrapy.Field()
```

last but not least my output looks like this:

```
    2017-02-26 20:44:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
    2017-02-26 20:44:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 8007,
    'downloader/request_count': 24,
    'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 24,
    'downloader/response_bytes': 757157,
    'downloader/response_count': 24,
    'downloader/response_status_count/200': 24,
    'finish_reason': 'finished',
    'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 4, 44, 41, 767181),
    'item_scraped_count': 2139,
    'log_count/DEBUG': 2164,
    'log_count/INFO': 11,
    'request_depth_max': 22,
    'response_received_count': 24,
    'scheduler/dequeued': 23,
    'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 23,
    'scheduler/enqueued': 23,
    'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 23,
    'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 27, 4, 39, 58, 834315)}
    2017-02-26 20:44:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

so it seems to me like I am not getting any errors, my items were scraped. if i had ran it with a -o myfile.json i could import myfile to my mongodb but the pipeline just isn't doing anything!

```
     mongo
     MongoDB shell version: 3.2.12
     connecting to: test
     Server has startup warnings: 
      2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]                              2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **    WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
     2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
     2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
     2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
     2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
     2017-02-24T18:51:24.276-0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
     > show dbs
     congress  0.078GB
     local     0.078GB
     > use congress
     switched to db congress
     > show collections
     members
     system.indexes
     > db.members.count()
     0
     >
```

I suspect my problem has to do with my settings file. I am new with scrapy and mongodb and I have a feeling I haven't told scrapy where my mongodb is correctly. 
here are some other sources I found, I tried using them as examples but everything I tried just lead to the same result(scraping was done, mongo was empty)
https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/
https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb
I have a bunch more sources but not enough reputation to post more unfortunately. 
anyway~ any thoughts would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You have a typo in your `MongoDBPipeline`: `def open_sipder(self,spider):` should be `open_spider`

Comment: opps... didn't fix the problem but thanks!

Comment: Also at `MongoDBPipeline(object): from_crawler(cls, crawler):` the two arguments of the `return cls()` statement should be comma separated. Regardless if this is the last step to go or not, I suggest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299704/what-are-good-ways-to-make-my-python-code-run-first-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips for some tips on basic testing/debugging when writing python scripts.

Comment: thanks! I ended up finding this error when the script actually ran. I appropriate the debug material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented out my line of code that said

`ITEM_PIPLINES = {'capstone.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,}`

and I uncommented the line of code that was already inside the settings file

`ITEM_PIPLINES = {
    'capstone.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline': 300,
}`

the only difference I can see is the newlines and this setting was set well below all my other settings.
after getting this to work I started getting python errors about the typos in my pipeline file. I figured out that my pipeline wasn't connecting because of the output before my items were being scraped:

`[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:[]`

after changed my settings i got this:

`[scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item piplines:['capstone.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline']`

Answer (score 0):

Typo where you're setting the DB name:

```
mongo_db=crawer.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
```

should be

```
mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
```

Hopefully that works!