# Error to create the txt file in loop

Tags: python

All IP address written in the file line by line and it will be executed by given command line. I want to save the result to each file with file's name is standing by each IP.

```
with open(list) as l:
    for line in l:
            file = line+".txt"
            os.system("whois "+line+" >> "+file)
```

list contains:

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

Errors:

```
sh: 3: .txt: not found
sh: 3: .txt: not found
sh: 3: .txt: not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `line = line.strip()` at beginning of your for loop to clear `\n` from your `line` variable, that will fix it.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300173/1233686) for examples of debugging methodologies for python. In your case, a `print()` statement can help you see what you are generating.

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad, that's so easy, now I just figured it out

Comment: No problem, we all been there! Welcome to the community.