# How to debug python system library modules

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-module

I am working with python standard library/some 3rd party module which is not working as expected. I used below steps to install the module.

```
sudo git clone http://github.com/someopensourcemodule.git
sudo python setup.py install
```

There is a failure which is seen in the above library which I am using, this library is used part of some other script(a complex script with lot of dynamic binding).

What I want to do is add a few print statements in foo module and also have an ability to step through the code. What options do I have?

1. Create a virtual environment.
2. Modify the source add prints and install using `python setup.py install` again
3. check the stdout for variable and stack value.
4. options which I can use pdb, pudb, or [Debugging tools in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299704/what-are-good-ways-to-make-my-python-code-run-first-time), this works well for modules. However I am not sure about modules which are installed using `python setup.py install`.

I want to know what are best practices which can be followed to debug module which is installed in system.

Comment: Use `python setup.py develop` if you're planning to make changes to the source code, then you don't need to keep reinstalling.

Comment: @jonrshape can you please provide more info on how does it work, where the build module gets stored(path). It would be really very helpful

Comment: It doesn't get "stored" anywhere, you can just edit the source code in your local clone of the repo.